# Find the first string in a string then get everything between quotes where it matches

Tags: php, regex, simple-html-dom

Hope the title made sense, I tried.

What I am trying to do is find the first occurrence of a particular string in a string then when I find that match get everything between the two double quotes where that match was made.

**For instance:**

Let say I am trying to find the first occurrence of ".mp3" in the following string

**Then my main string looks like this**

My string is actually HTML from `$string = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/something')` FYI

```
$string = 'something: "http://www.example.com/someaudio.mp3?variable=1863872368293283289&and=someotherstuff" that: "http://www.example.com/someaudio.mp3?variable=jf89f8f897f987f&and=someotherstuff" this: "http://www.example.com/someaudio.mp3?variable=123&and=someotherstuff" beer: "http://www.example.com/someaudio.mp3?variable=876sf&and=someotherstuff"';
```

At this point, I would like to find the first `.mp3`, then I need the entire url located within the double quotes where the match is made

**Output should be**

```
http://www.example.com/someaudio.mp3?variable=1863872368293283289&and=someotherstuff
```

I already know how to use `strpos` to find a match in php, problem is that from there how do I get the entire url between the quotes? Is this even possible?

Comment: Come on this is a legit question

Comment: Could you show us what you have done so far please ?

Comment: What if `mp3` is not in a URL ?

Comment: `(?<=")[^"]*\.mp3[^"]*(?=")` https://regex101.com/r/1nrDsf/1

Comment: So you just downvote the question and vote to close because the lack of "I have tried `.*` but it din't work". Funny because it looks absolutely fine to me. Easy to understand and obviously OP did research but doesn't know how to use regex for this.

Comment: I give +1 because it is a good question.

Comment: Thank you @bobblebubble I would have shown an example, but I had no clue where to start.

Comment: @CesarBielich I just wanted to put an answer, but the sheriffs were faster :p You can use `preg_match` like an answer does already to get one match only or *the first match*. Maybe a simple pattern similar @sln's pattern will be enough: [`if(preg_match('~[^"]+\.mp3[^"]*~', $str, $out)) { echo $out[0]; } else { echo "no match"; }`](https://eval.in/1099478) which uses [negated class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

Comment: The "put on hold as off-topic" explanation doesn't seem to me to apply to this question. The question **is not** seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working"); it's asking **how** to accomplish a specific goal. _Assuming_ the asker is unfamiliar with regex, I can't imagine what else they should have done before asking this. Is it a duplicate? If so it should be flagged as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to use [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with the optional `$matches` argument.

[The regex in question will be something like](https://regex101.com/r/g4cmdn/1)

```php
$r = '".*\.mp3.*"';
```

You'll note that I've glossed over *all* of the subtleties of what might be meant by "a url located within double quotes".

The use of the $matches argument may feel a little weird; it used to be a normal way for functions to work, and still is in languages like C++.

```php
$m = [];
if(preg_match($r, $subject_string, $m)){
  $the_thing_you_want = $m[0];
}
```

Comment: @sln 's comment to the main question is very likely the regex you actually want: "`(?<=")[^"]*\.mp3[^"]*(?=")`". My only hesitation is that they're using some heavier syntax than you might want if you've never used regex before. "`[^"]*\.mp3[^"]*`" will get you 95% of the way.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways of doing this. Using [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) (and a couple of other string manipulation functions) is one. As you mention, using `strpos` alone, only gets you to your first ".mp3". So you need to do combine it with something else. Let's have a play:

```
$str = <<<EOF
something: "http://www.example.com/someaudio.mp3?variable=1863872368293283289&and=someotherstuff"
that: "http://www.example.com/someaudio.mp3?variable=jf89f8f897f987f&and=someotherstuff"
this: "http://www.example.com/someaudio.mp3?variable=123&and=someotherstuff"
beer: "http://www.example.com/someaudio.mp3?variable=876sf&and=someotherstuff"
EOF;

$first_mp3_location = strpos($str, ".mp3");
//Get the location of the start of the first ".mp3" string
$first_quote_location = $first_mp3_location - strpos(strrev(substr($str, 0, $first_mp3_location)), '"');
/*
 * Working backwards, get the first location of a '"',
 * then subtract the first location of the ".mp3" from that number
 * to get the first location of a '"', the right way up.
 */
$first_qoute_after_mp3_location = strpos($str, '"', $first_mp3_location);
//Then finally get the location of the first '"' after the ".mp3" string

var_dump(substr($str, $first_quote_location, $first_qoute_after_mp3_location - $first_quote_location));
//Finally, do a substr to get the string you want.
```

This is a pretty <s>retarded</s> longwinded way of getting to what you need to get to, and you're probably better off using regex, but there *is* a way of doing it with just strpos and its buddies `strrev` and `substr`.

Comment: All that returns dumped is `string(11) "something: "`

Comment: Try again, have a look here: https://3v4l.org/ighBv

Comment: Actually, your example is working but I have my HTML in a variable and it doesn't seem to work with your example using `EOF`

Comment: I edited my code to show more exactly how my string is contained.

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference, here, I used the exact same string as you have written: https://3v4l.org/7EIgN